# How do I get Waterfox to work?

Tags: files, downloads, budgie

I installed Waterfox but it is not available as an application, just a folder. How do I get it to work like a normal app? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you install it or did you download the source? we need more information as to what you did? if it is installed did you try to run it?

Comment: @JohnOrion [Waterfox is available on Windows, macOS, Linux, and Android](https://www.waterfoxproject.org/downloads).

Comment: yeah i removed that .. just found that .. seems to come in a tar.gz file .. trying to download to see if its a precompiled or if it needs to be compiled

Comment: @JohnOrion All I did was download the tar.gz file off their site. Not sure how to get it working from here.

Comment: @JohnOrion I also tried to install Firefox and I have the same issue. There is no application to use, it just comes with a folder full of files.

Comment: creating an answer now .. be done soon :D

Comment: @EliahKagan Ill give that a try, but I have the same issue with everything I install. Even when I got Firefox, it just came as a folder with files. No application to open and use.

Comment: @Goolag you seem to indicate that you are having additional problems installing anything. Could you run the following in a terminal `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install firefox`. If those commands give you errors you should [ask a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) about the root cause of them.

Comment: dont know how you are installing firefox .. but to install firefox in ubuntu you just open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get install firefox` and it will install it and ad shortcuts for it on the menu ... lol J.Stames .. you beat me to it

Comment: The solution that J. Stames gave is a better solution because then apt will update it when there is an update .. the waterfox will not update since its a standalone download

Answer (score 0):

To run this you will have to create your own shortcut to it.

You can right click on your desktop and Create a launcher

[image]

you would probably be better off browsing to the file with the little folder icon .. you are looking for the file that says waterfox .. in the waterfox folder ..

it most likely will ask you to make it executable when you first run the shortcut .. say make it executable and you should be all set

you can add an icon too if you can find one for it or just leave it as the default "no icon"

it can be run from terminal also by opening the directory in terminal and typing `./waterfox` but the terminal has to stay open or the browser will close and the terminal will show a bunch of stuff you dont have to worry about

If you use Nautilus for your file manager then launch Nautilus and click on `Computer` and locate the application you want to run in `/usr/share/applications` click on it to highlight it and press `Ctrl+C` to copy it. Then click on Desktop on the left and press `Ctrl+V` to paste it. 
Once pasted .. right click on it and go to `Properties` and then the `Permissions` tab .. and make sure that the Execute check box is checked then close the properties and Nautilus and your icon should be on your desktop and functional

Comment: When I right-click on the desktop I don't see an option to create a launcher. Note I am using Budgie so it may be slightly different.

Comment: @Goolag I updated the answer .. hopefully that will help